# Ubuntu 21.04. Question about using an old app

Tags: backup, security

I found a Linux app called LuckyBackup. I checked the changelog and it was last updated in 2018. Safe to use an old abandoned app like this? Or best to not use it?

I’m new to Linux.

The LuckyBackup UI looks good, but there’s other apps I can use if LuckyBackup is not safe.

Comment: **Safe?** That's a matter of opinion but there are a lot of red flags.  Not being updated in years means that it could have unpatched security flaws or serious bugs.  The developer is unknown so who knows if it was even secure and bug-free to begin with. In fact, it says there are bugs.  It's not in Ubuntu repos so nobody from Canonical or the Ubuntu community has eyes on it. Not being in repos means you'll have to install it some other way and being new to Linux this is hard and you might break something. You're presumably trusting it with valuable information, so that's a bit scary.

Comment: If you are new to Linux/Ubuntu, stick with software in official repos unless you absolutely need to use some particular software that isn't. And anything not in repos is up to you to determine if you trust the devs and contributiors not only be honest and not malicious, but to be savvy enough to write good and "safe" software and to keep it well maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This helps me understand the big picture. I'll avoid non-repo apps and use due diligence if I need to use a non-repo app.